# What is the maximum capacity of databases in Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and 2008?

Tags: sql-server

What is the maximum capacity of databases in Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and 2008? How much data can a single database can hold? I want a database that can store unlimited data - which version is better?

I am using ASP.NET/C# as a front end.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow..Read the FAQ before asking questions..

Answer (score 1):

**SQL 2005:** Max DB Size: 524,258 terabytes, Max DB File Size: 16 terabytes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.90).aspx

**SQL 2008:** Max DB Size: 524,272 terabytes, Max DB File Size: 16 terabytes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: +1: @simran, 524,272 terabytes. Is that enough or do you think you'll need more?